# HTTP 500 error trying to import contacts

Tags: import, 500

Running CiviCRM 5.11 plugin on WordPress. This is a fresh install.

Running on a shared hosting service (Arvixe).

PHP release is 7.1

The Import file is less than 10,000 records. One time, it was successful but all subsequent attempts with different files fail with an HTTP 500 Internal Server Error.

Arvixe tech support has set file/directory permissions but won't tell me exactly what they did.

Time out is set to 300 in PHP

What else can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I am switching to DigitalOcean. Works fine there. Bye bye Arvixe.